# How to get only the date value from DateTime and count it?

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

How to compare only the date from the DateTime using LINQ to Entities and then sum it with another query.

I would like to achive the following
- to count the number of Type having the value "Complete" and to count the Today's date and display their sum in a textbox.

```
 var query_test = (from c in this.db.Documents
                   where c.Type == "Complete" && c.Date == DateTime.Now.Date
                   select c).Count();
```

when i run this query, I get an exception

> "'System.Nullable' does not contain a definition for
>   'Date' and no extension method 'Date' accepting a first argument of
>   type 'System.Nullable' could be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) "

I have tried the below query from other similar posts, but still it doesn't work

```
var q1 = (this.db.Documents.Where(r => r.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") == DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") && r.Type == "Complete").Count());
```

kindly help

Comment: What error do you get from the second version (the lambda notation)? The same error?

Comment: its look like object c is null don't know why

Comment: I get this exception for the second query- LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this.

```
var query_test = (from c in this.db.Documents
                   where c.Type == "Complete" && c.Date == DateTime.Today
                   select c).Count();
```

if you aren't sure if there is a time element you could truncate it.

```
var query_test = (from c in this.db.Documents
                   where c.Type == "Complete" && EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(c.Date) == DateTime.Today
                   select c).Count();
```

Comment: I tried this too, but i have 0 values, I guess here it includes time from Today's date too

Comment: @user1221765 i've modified my answer, you can truncate the time aspect of the date before comparing.

Comment: this modified one looks fine. Thanks a lot. one last question, can you pls provide the similar SQL query also, so that I can compare the SQL query result to my linq result

Comment: use a tool like linqpad to run your queries, it shows the generated sql. Or you could use EfProf or sql query analyzer.